# Writing IEqualityComparator for HashSet<Tuple<T, int>>

Tags: c#

I want to write an extension to C#'s standard HashSet to count occurances (I know, use a dict. But I'm curious if and how... :)).

So I have:

```
public class CountingHashSet{
    public CountingHashSet(IEqualityComparer<T> comparator)
    {
        hashSet = new HashSet<Tuple<T, int>>(new EqualityAdapter<T>(comparator));
    }
}
```

I now want to write an Adapter for the `IEqualityComparator<T>` interface, so that the provided comparator is used on the First element, `T`, of the Tuples in the HashSet.

I came up with something like this, which the compiler does not allow:

```
public class EqualityAdapter<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : Tuple<T, int>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<T> comparator;

    public EqualityAdapter(IEqualityComparer<T> comparator)
    {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return comparator.Equals(x.First, y.First);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return comparator.GetHashCode(obj.First);
    }
}
```

Please help. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How can `T` be a `Tuple<T, int>`?  I think you meant `public class EqualityAdapter<T> : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<T, int>>`

Comment: Well that was easy. :) Thanks! Put it as an answer and ill accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generics are all wrong.  `T` cannot be `Tuple<T, int>`.  Instead your comparer should be on `Tuple<T, int>` and then you don't need any constraints.

```
public class TupleFirstItemEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<Tuple<T, int>> 
{
    private IEqualityComparer<T> comparator;

    public TupleFirstItemEqualityComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> comparator)
    {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    public bool Equals(Tuple<T, int> x, Tuple<T, int> y)
    {
        return comparator.Equals(x.First, y.First);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Tuple<T, int> obj)
    {
        return comparator.GetHashCode(obj.First);
    }
}
```